# Wordpress wp_query get two last inserted posts from two categories in one query

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the code below to make a query in Wordpress and get two last inserted posts from one category. I have to make two queries one for each category to get the results i need. Is it possible in one query to get the two last inserted posts from two categories? Total results of posts four, two from one category and two from the other, one query. Any help appreciated.

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'posts_per_page'      => '3',
        'order'               => 'DESC',
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
        'no_found_rows'       => true,
        'cat' => '33',

    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to get both categories in the query?

I found this somewhere else

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228797/get-latest-posts-from-multiple-categories

> ```
>   $args = array( 
>     'posts_per_page' => 5,
>     'category' => array(15,16,17,18,19) 
>     );
> ```
>
> You can't just add the numbers in a list but I can't find any
>   documentation that the category element allows multiples (as the name
>   is category)
>
> The other option is to use wp_query and category__in
>
> ```
>     $query = new WP_Query(
>      array(
>       'category__in' => array(15,16,17,18,19),
>       'posts_per_page' => 5,
>       'post_type' => 'post',
>      )
>      );
>     if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
>      while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
>       $query->the_post();
>       // do something
>      }
>     }
>     wp_reset_postdata();
> ```
>
> These will get the 5 last posts from any of those categories, if you
>   want to get a post from each of them then the query needs to be a lot
>   different

My version would be:

```
     $query = new WP_Query(
      array(
       'category__in' => array(15,16),
       'posts_per_page' => 4,
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'order' => 'DESC',
       'orderby' => 'date'
      )
      );
     if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
       $query->the_post();
       // do something
      }
     }
     wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: This is a great start, the only problem here would be that if the last 4 posts were all in category 15, you would not receive anything from category 16. There needs to be a way to ensure that you get at least one post from each category.